# PHP Method Can't Access Array Given On Class Property

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
class MyClass {

public $result53 = array();
public $combination53 = array();

public function combine53($start, $choose_, $arr, $n) {

    $result53 = $this->$result53;
    $combination53 = $this->$combination53;

    //--- some code here
}
```

but `$result53 = $this->$result53;` and `$combination53 = $this->$combination53;` marked as `NULL`. How to access class property (array) from inside method? thank you.

Comment: create the class object and then access the class property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$result53 = $this->result53;
$combination53 = $this->combination53;
```

remove `$` before variable name

Comment: Sounds like a typo to me